# Upfront reason for closing a question needed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Could a succint version of the reason for closing a question be given in main? Since the closing of a question usually implies some negativity, it would be nice if at least those closed due to "non-negative" reason of merely being a duplicate were noted as such, for example,
Did Pooh learn English from Christopher Robin? [closed as a duplicate of this question]
where "this question" is a link to the first time the question was asked. Even if the moderators don't want to bother with specifying other reasons, it seems to me that this one reason ought to be made explicit with the relevant questions in main.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The [last closed answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58217/value-in-use-now-and-value-to-be-used-later) gives the reason: `closed as off topic... Questions on English Language and Usage - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to English language and usage, within the scope defined in the faq.`

Comment: And for [duplicates](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52901/is-the-sentence-were-done-grammatically-correct): `closed as exact duplicate... This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question. See the FAQ.` And the question is prefixed with a link to the other: `Possible Duplicate: 
I'm done or I've done`

Comment: @Hugo I think what Hexagon means is indicating the reason on the main page, or in question lists in general. There, we recently got the note "[migrated]" in addition to simply "[closed]". The way I understand it, he suggests that we split it even further, into [migrated], [duplicate], [off-topic], [too localized], etc. where the word "duplicate" is a link to the original question.

Comment: Presumably the protocol here is to downvote the question if you don't feel strongly that the requested feature should be pushed for, so I'll do that. If resources were no object, I would vote for this to be a "user-configurable" feature, so Hexagon could enable it if he wanted. I'd probably not do so myself because I wouldn't want more "clutter" onscreen all the time, and it would sometimes reduce the number of questions per page. But resources are finite, so I'd rather see the backroom boys working on more useful features.

Answer (score 5):

This is now partially implemented. Questions closed as duplicates now get a " [duplicate]" appended to the title, rather than just " [closed]".

[image: Duplicate notice]

So together with " [migrated]", that makes three different notices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary to report exactly the reason why a question has been closed in the pages listing questions.

There is no negativity in a closed question, but I don't see in which way reporting the exact reason for closing a question would reduced the negativity of a closed question; even if the page would use *[off-topic]*, the meaning is still "closed because it was off-topic."

Answer (score -2):

Here is my best advice: never let anyone know that you are going to use the answer to help you write a computer program. Make it seem that you are a casual scholar who is fascinated with the English language for its own sake. The users on the site have emotions, and they do not have empathy for computer people. They do, however, have pity to spare for language enthusiasts or [well-meaning tutors](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97102/medicine-is-good-when-your-family-gives-it-to-you-not-when-your-friend-gives-yo).

Comment: It's funny you think that, since over half of the mods on this site and a fair number of chat regulars and 10K+ rep users are "computer people."

Comment: Leaving aside for a moment that I fail to understand how this is an answer to the question at hand, Kit is precisely right. In fact she herself does programming for a living — as do Robusto, Matt Ellen, JSBangs, tchrist (do you even realize who tchrist is?), myself, and countless others. Barely a day goes by in our chat 
without a programming-related discussion. Lots of the 3k users here are also 3k users on SO — and most of them *came* here via SO in the first place. There was even an [official SE podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/) a while back discussing that.

Comment: @RegDwighт it seems I was misunderstood. i took it for granted that people are most impatient with their own kind. i work at a government agency and i know i'd be impatient with someone from my agency asking a question on here that shows they are too lazy to look up a regulation they are supposed to be familiar with.